# JMSItemReader reconnecting to Solace as per Chunk size

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jms, solace

I have Spring batch app which connects to Solace queue, polls the records as long as message are there in queue or receiver time out is reached. I'm using chunk based processing But I could see my batch app reconnects to Solace for every chunk it is trying to process. As far as my understanding is concerned Connection to Solace should happen only at once and SolSession should start/end as per defined chunk size..Is my understanding correct or this is expected behaviour?

**Spring batch application logs**

```
2021-04-01 11:54:17.033  INFO 11144 --- [           main] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=55555' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 1, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
2021-04-01 11:54:17.111  INFO 11144 --- [           main] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connected to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=55555' (smfclient 1)
2021-04-01 11:54:17.158  INFO 11144 --- [           main] com.solacesystems.jms.SolSession         : SolSession started.
Received data of size 100
2021-04-01 11:54:24.122  INFO 11144 --- [           main] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Channel Closed (smfclient 1)
2021-04-01 11:54:24.122  INFO 11144 --- [           main] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=55555' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 2, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
2021-04-01 11:54:24.187  INFO 11144 --- [           main] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connected to host 'orig=tcp://localhost:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=55555' (smfclient 2)
2021-04-01 11:54:24.219  INFO 11144 --- [           main] com.solacesystems.jms.SolSession         : SolSession started.
Received data of size 100
2021-04-01 11:54:31.036  INFO 11144 --- [           main] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Channel Closed (smfclient 2)
2021-04-01 11:54:31.036  INFO 11144 --- [           main] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://tcp://localhost:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=55555' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 3, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
2021-04-01 11:54:31.098  INFO 11144 --- [           main] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connected to host 'orig=tcp://tcp://localhost:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=localhost, port=55555' (smfclient 3)
2021-04-01 11:54:31.145  INFO 11144 --- [           main] com.solacesystems.jms.SolSession         : SolSession started.
```

Below is my Spring batch Configuration class:

```java
@EnableJms
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchJmsConfig {
    
    
    public static final Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBatchJmsConfig.class.getName());
    
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    
    @Autowired
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    public CustomItemWriter writer;
    
    
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory cFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory=new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        factory.setPubSubDomain(false);
        return factory;
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter=new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
    
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public JmsItemReader<HcpSample1> hcpJmsItemReader(MessageConverter messageConverter){
        
        JmsItemReader<HcpSample1> hcpJmsItemReader=new JmsItemReader();
        hcpJmsItemReader.setJmsTemplate(jmsTemplate);
        hcpJmsItemReader.setItemType(HcpSample1.class);
        return hcpJmsItemReader;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<HcpSample1> hcpFlatFileItemWriter(){
        FlatFileItemWriter<HcpSample1> hcpFlatFileItemWriter=new FlatFileItemWriter();
        hcpFlatFileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(hcp->hcp.toString());
        hcpFlatFileItemWriter.setLineSeparator(System.lineSeparator());
        hcpFlatFileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("hcp.txt"));
        return hcpFlatFileItemWriter;
        
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public Job readJmsAndWriteToFileJob() {
        
        return jobBuilFactory.get("readJmsAndWriteToFileJob").flow(step1()).end().build();
    }
    
    
    private Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<HcpSample1,HcpSample1>chunk(100).
                reader(hcpJmsItemReader(messageConverter())).writer(writer).build();
    }
    

}
```

`CustomItemWriter`:

```java
@Component
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<HcpSample1> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends HcpSample1> items) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Received data of size " +items.size());
        
    }

}
```

`application.properties`:

```
solace.jms.host=tcp://localhost:55555
solace.jms.msg-vpn=DevVPN
solace.jms.client-username=test
solace.jms.client-password=test
spring.jms.template.default-destination=SpringBatchTestQueue
spring.jms.template.receive-timeout=2s
logging.level.com.solacesystems=INFO
```

Note I'm using Spring batch along with `solace-spring-boot-starter` for Solace autoconfiguration.

Comment: The JmsItemreader does not re-open a JMS connection for each chunk. It will use the same connection for the entire job. If the item reader returns `null` after the timeout, the job will be finished and that's when the connection is closed. Do you have a single job execution?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes ..my use case is to run this job every hour and process all messages

Answer (score 0):

The JmsItemreader does not re-open a JMS connection for each chunk. It will use the same connection for the entire job. If the item reader returns null after the timeout, the job will be finished and that's when the connection is closed.

> yes ..my use case is to run this job every hour and process all messages

In this case, it is normal that you see a new connection for each scheduled run (ie a new job execution).

Comment: logs which I have shared are for one scheduled run only..As per logs shared in above question, JMSItemReader is reconnecting to solace for every chunk size of 100 messages..

Comment: You said you run the job every hour, meaning every hour you have a new job execution, unless your ItemReader's timeout is more than an hour. As I said, Spring Batch does not create a connection per chunk. If you are sure you have a single job run in which you have multiple connections, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient manner.

Comment: Hi could you please check updated question..I have shared application logs as well batch job configuration

Comment: I don't see any update: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66902014/revisions apart from `added 33 characters in body` `Spring batch application logs`. If you are sure you have a single job run in which you have multiple connections, please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient manner.